# Point two domain names to single wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, dns

I've got a single site install of wordpress 4.7.3. I've got everything set up and going at [domainname].com

I also own [domainname].org via a different registrar and would like to point .org to the .com website (not via redirect) such that a user on the .org site always sees the .org in their url.

Is this possible? I've already tried this https://myjeeva.com/mapping-multiple-domains-into-single-instance-of-wordpress.html while pointing the .org DNS records to the same ip as .com but no dice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: we can help you if you specify the registrar of yourdomain.org

Comment: .com is namecheap and .org is dreamhost. I'd like to move everything to namecheap but the powers at be above me would rather migrate everything to dreamhost so I'm a bit stuck in the middle trying to find solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the belp of dreamhost
https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214694348-Basic-DNS-records
Try to add a cname record point

Answer (score 0):

- Go to WordPress installed root directory and look for wp-config.php file
- Place below lines after the table_prefix line; order is very important in      wp-config.php , more info

**/*

*Handle multi domain into single instance of wordpress installation

*/

**define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);**

**define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);**

Go to wordpress admin page and take a look at Settings -> General. You will have WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) will be in disabled state.  It means your wordpress installation dynamic enoungh to accomadate both domain address.

Answer (score -1):

please check this [url](http://please%20check%20this%20url,%20it%20can%20help%20you%20to%20solve%20your%20problem%20[enter%20link%20description%20here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16187/i-have-domain-com-and-domain-org-to-the-same-site-should-i-use-redirects-to-avo)), it can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: this worked, i needed to add the .org domain to namecheap so that requests to the shared hosting would hit my wp instance. Thanks!